# What are the options for persisting data on Apple Watch?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-5

I'm using Apple Watch to collect sensor(e.g. accelerator) data, and need to store the data first on the Watch and send to iPhone afterwards. What are the possible ways to store the data?

As it would be a large amount of data, NSUserDefault apparently is not suitable in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite works on Watch. The below SQLDataAccess.swift will work.
https://github.com/pmurphyjam/SQLiteDemo